# How to change label state from another mxml?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have two mxmls and label (with Id="labelID") in mxmlOne. What i want is to change its visibility from function from another mxmlTwo.

I tried to access through id and change visible to "false". What i miss? I gave mxmlOne id="mxmlOneID" and trying this way:

```
mxmlOneID.labelID.visible="false";
```

Could you point me where to dig? I'm novice in flex and AS.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I'm a bit confused by your question.  I don't understand which mxml components you are using or how the two relate to each other in terms of hierarchy.  Can you share enough code in order to provide a runnable sample of the problem?

Comment: Get rid of the quotes. Visible accepts a boolean value, not a String. Didn't you get a compiler warning?

Comment: @drkstr1 I would expect the compiler to automatically convert "false" the string to false the Boolean.

Comment: @Reboog711 I assumed that code was being called in Actionscript, as it is not valid MXML. In Actionscript the String "false" would typecast as true, and throw a compiler warning for the shoddy behavior.

Comment: @Reboog711 I forgot to mention that mxmlTwo is included in mxmlOne.

Comment: @drkstr1 Thanks for hint, I had another error on this string something like mxmlOne is not visible.

Comment: @drkstr1 I did a test; and you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user2791999, The better way is use Events, you can try:

First MXML: `dispatchEvent (new Event("nameEvent"))`

Second MXML: `addEventListener ("nameEvent",function,true)`.

For more information: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html

or you can use: parent, parentDocument, owner, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.nameOfVar

For more information: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e3a.html

Comment: Your event suggestion assumes a certain hierarchy between first MXML and second MXML; however that hierarchy is not clear from the original post.

Comment: @Laotshi Thanks a lot, that kind of information is what i was looking for.

Comment: @Reboog711 Thank you too, actually i have some hierarchy. Even more now i see that it better to use already existing events in these mxmls.